# Optimising dual SVM: why do some authors drop constraints?

Tags: classification, svm, optimization, libsvm

In Hastie's Elements of Statistical Learning the dual problem is  put as

$$
\begin{align}
\text{arg min}_\alpha \quad &\ \frac{1}{2}\alpha^\top Q\, \alpha_i- \sum_i \alpha_i\\
\text{subject to}\quad &\ \forall i:0\le\alpha_i\le C\\ &\ \sum_i y_i \alpha_i = 0
\end{align}
$$

I implemented a dual coordinate descent method based on Hsieh et al.'s [A Dual Coordinate Descent Method for Large-scale Linear SVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/cddual.pdf) but they state that the dual problem is

$$
\begin{align}
\text{arg min}_\alpha \quad &\ \frac{1}{2}\alpha^\top Q\, \alpha_i- \sum_i \alpha_i\\
\text{subject to}\quad &\ \forall i:0\le\alpha_i\le C
\end{align}
$$

In other words, they dropped the second constraint. I ran the implementation and indeed the constraint is not met after the algorithm finishes. Note that [LIBLINEAR](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) uses the same approach with the constraint $\sum_i y_i \alpha_i = 0$ dropped.

It doesn't seem legit to me to simply drop constraints, so why are some authors doing it?

Comment: First notice that the constraint in the first formulation comes from setting the derivative w.r.t $\beta_0$  to zero (I'm using Hastie's book notation). Now see Eq. (3) in the paper that you cite.

Comment: So to answer shortly, the matrix $Q$ in the first formulation is different from the matrix $Q$ in the second formulation. Actually $Q_2 = Q_1 + yy^{\top}$, where $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_l)^{\top}$.

Comment: Not sure whether I understand. The literal formulation in Hastie (p.420, Eq 12.13) is $L_D  = \sum_i \alpha_i - 1/2 \sum_i\sum_{i'} \alpha_i \alpha_{i'} y_i y_{i'} x_i x_{i'}^\top$, so in my first equation $Q_{ij} = y_i y_j x_i^\top x_j$, which is identical to the formulation in the Hsieh paper.

Comment: OK I seem to have missed this post dealing with the same question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246404/linear-constraint-in-svm-optimization?rq=1